# Polynomials Extended

Tags: polynomials

What is the name of an more extended polynomial?

With parameters $\alpha = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$

$P_{n}(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{2n} \alpha_{i}x^{n-i}$

Example of 3rd order:

$P_{3}(x) = x^3 + 2x^2 + 3x + 4 + \frac{5}{x} + \frac{6}{x^2} + \frac{7}{x^3}$

Comment: Sometimes it is called a [Laurent polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_polynomial).

Comment: Polynomials in $x$ and $\frac 1x$ are *Laurent polynomials*. Their completion for the $x$-adic topology is the set of *Laurent series*.